# fetching data and rendering react

Tags: reactjs, json, state, react-functional-component

I have a realtime application that fetches a set of data that remains static and another set every second.
The problem is that event if I test the application with an imported json instead of fetching it and set the app state with that json, I have errors because the state on mount is empty... I tried to insert some conditional like

```
{data && <MainPage/>}
```

but still have errors on MainPage children like "Cannot read properties of undefined (reading '0')" because I'm passing parts of the json to the children as props.
How can I solve this?

Comment: Can you provide the code for `MainPage`

Answer (score 0):

You should try these types of conditions

```js
{data ? <MainPage/> : null}

{data ? <MainPage/> : <Home/>}
```

Comment: doesn't solve the problem unfortunately

Comment: @Velleda you need to share more code regarding it

Answer (score 0):

If the data is array you can check `data.length != 0`
or if it's object you can check if it's empty or not

Comment: the problem is that I have all different kind of errors because it doesn't set the state to props.. why that?

Comment: can you please provide the code may be there is issue while you are setting state